# Magento - MultiSite - Share Shopping Cart?

Tags: magento

I am trying to set up 2 sites under 1 magento installation.  I used the following guide and creating 2 root categories:
http://www.terranetwork.net/blog/2011/11/magento-multi-store-on-shared-cpanel-hosting-with-parked-domains/

The missing code from the .htaccess section of the guide is:
SetEnvIf Host .*example.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=example
SetEnvIf Host .*example.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

It is working good however the shopping cart isn't shared between both sites.  Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

How did you set your stores up in Magento? They have to be setup a particular way in order for them to work together.

I believe that the two stores have to be created to be apart of the same website in order to share the same cart.